# nautilus shows only simplified browse window

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat, nautilus

If I do
nautilus .
in my terminal it shows the browsing window doesn't have sideview, location bar and other icons. But if I open file browser from Applications-> System Tools -> File Browser then it looks like a featured browser, it has location bar on top and so on. How can I let nautilus invoke File Browser that has featured options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Terminal : `$ nautilus --browser`

? Gnome 2 ? Please use `$ gconf-editor` to set up Nautilus :

→ apps >> nautilus → preferences

... Then tick "always_use_browser" and "always_use_location_entry"

---

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, the "always_use_browser" was not ticked, now it works just the way I wanted after ticking that option.